# Show different divs for different routes but in the same file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have nodejs express backend using static file management, one html file where i have 2 divs. For root route i want to display div1 and for the any other route i want to display div2. How can i do that?

**index.js**

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client')))

app.get('/:gameCode', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client'))
    // but with visible div2 and invisible div1
})
```

**index.html**

```
<div1 class="active">div1</div1>
<div2 class="inactive">div2</div2>
```

**style.css**

```
.active { display: block }
.inactive { display: none }
```

I can't do it with 2 different html files

Or maybe do it on frontend - read the url and check if it's a root or not and then switch visibility depending on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a frontend solution to that.

**index.js - frontend**

```
if (window.location.pathname.length > 1) {
    document.querySelector('#div1').classList.remove('active')
    document.querySelector('#div1').classList.add('inactive')
    document.querySelector('#div2').classList.remove('inactive')
    document.querySelector('#div2').classList.add('active')
}
```